# Storing sessions with passportjs, Express and monogodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, passport.js

I'm having trouble getting sessions with mongodb to work properly. I've setup the following code which, without a problem, creates the user.

I can also see my `sessions` database being populated which looks like this:

[image]
<sub>(source: [wes.io](http://wes.io/LNbg/content))</sub>

Problem is, I am never at a logged in state. It works fine if I just use memory to store the session, but when moving to mongodb, it doesn't work. Here is where I think the problem code is, but you can see the entire app here: http://wes.io/LNVg

```
passport.use(new LocalStrategy(
  function(username, password, done) {
    console.log('Trying to log in as '.green, username);
    
    User.findOne({ name: username }, function(err, user) {
      if (err) {return done(err); }

      if(user) {
        console.log('Found user with the username of'.green,user); 
        done(null, user);
      } 

      else {
        console.log('No user found...  '.red.inverse, username, password);
        var user = new User();
        user.name = username;
        user.username = username;
        user.password = password;
        user.save(function(err){
          if(err) { throw err; }
          console.log('User created and saved'.green, user)
          done(null, user);
        })
      };

    });
  }
));

passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
  done(null, user);
});

passport.deserializeUser(function(user, done) {
  done(null, user);
});

app.configure(function(){
  app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000);
  app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
  app.set('view engine', 'jade');
  app.use(express.cookieParser());
  app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
  app.use(require('less-middleware')({ src: __dirname + '/public' }));
  app.use(express.favicon());
  app.use(express.bodyParser());
  app.use(express.logger('dev'));
  app.use(express.methodOverride());
  app.use(express.session({ 
        store: store
      , secret: 'applecake'
      , cookie : {
            maxAge : 604800 // one week
        }
  }));
  app.use(passport.initialize());
  app.use(passport.session()); 
  app.use(app.router);
});
```

Edit: here is the code for the session store:

```
var express = require('express')
  , colors = require('colors')
  , routes = require('./routes')
  , mongoose = require('mongoose')
  , SessionStore = require("session-mongoose")(express)
  , store = new SessionStore({
        url: "mongodb://localhost/fb-session",
        interval: 120000 // expiration check worker run interval in millisec (default: 60000)
    })
  , Schema = mongoose.Schema
  , flash = require('connect-flash')
  , userz = require('./routes/user')
  , http = require('http')
  , path = require('path')
  , passport = require('passport')
  , LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;
```

Comment: can you post the code for setting up your session store?

Comment: I've added it, please let me know if you can help

Comment: Try using https://github.com/masylum/connect-mongodb for session store - it works flawlessly for me in the exact same scenario

Comment: I have tried that and had the exact same results... will try again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it was an issue with the serialize and deserialze methods. Here is my example with the name although it will be changed to a user ID

```
passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
    done(null, user.name);
});
passport.deserializeUser(function(name, done) {
    done(null, { name: name });
});
```